# Regex for searching text in line with "wildcards"?

Tags: regex, windows, string, search, line

I want to search through 250 files with a program which supports regex but I don't know how to build the query.

This is an example file:

```
//////////////////////////////Crown Area Effects///////////////////////////////

// Super Spies
DbAreaEffectInfo SuperSpies
{
    name = text_carea_sprspies_name
    desc = text_carea_sprspies_desc
    effects = [
        // scale sabotage super-effect duration

        EffectDuration {
            range = SpaceTime

            player = Self
            // which effect's duration is this scaling
            effect = "SabotageBuilding"
            scale = 1.25
        }

        EffectDuration {
            range = SpaceTime

            player = Self
            // which effect's duration is this scaling
            effect = "ImprovedSabotageBuilding"
            scale = 1.25
        }

        EffectSpeed {
            range = Global
            mask = Spies
            player = Self
            // 25% faster
            scale = 1.25
        }

        EffectMaxHitPoints {
            range = Global
            mask = Spies
            player = Self
            // 25% more hit points
            scale = 1.25
        }

        EffectVisualGlow {
            range = Global
            mask = Spies
            player = Self
            GlowType = Good
            OwnerOnly = true
            Icon = icon_crown_superspies_s
            Tooltip = text_carea_sprspies_name
            VTooltip = vtt_power_unitinfo_SuperSpies
        }

        EffectIsACrown {
            range = Global
            mask = Spies
            player = Self

            crownType = kCrownType_Imperial
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to look for a pattern like this one:

```
<ANYTHING, EVEN NULL>//<ANYTHING, EVEN NULL><MyString><AnyThing, EVEN NULL>
```

For example for this:

```
<anything>//<anything>super<anything>
```

Which would yield this results:

```
 // scale sabotage super-effect duration
```

What regex query would give me the wanted results?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Edit:

I am using Effective File Search - http://www.sowsoft.com/search.htm

Comment: Sooo, what language/regex engine is this?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html is your destination :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard regex wildcard is `.` (for one character). Arbitrary repetition is represented by `*`. So this should do the trick for you:

```
~//(.*)super(.*)~
```

Depending on your regex engine you might be able/have to leave out the delimiters `~`. Also, since `.` by default does not match line breaks, the second wildcard will always go to the end of the line and the `super` has to appear on the same line as `//`.

Comment: thanks ^.^ will accept in 4 mins

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution is to use

```
grep pattern /path/to/files*
```

in a shell.

You can download [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) to have `grep` for windows.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm on Windows 7

Comment: What else are you on? How is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*//.*?(STRINGYOUWANTTOSEARCHFOR).*$
```

Assuming pcre/perlre style.

In perlre, use

```
^\s*//.*?(\QSTRINGYOUWANTTOSEARCHFOR\E).*$
```

to prevent strange interpretations in the string you are looking for

Other regex engines/flavours have different syntax, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for comparisons

Comment: You should add an additional wildcard to the end, because he wants to return the whole comment in case of a match.

Comment: @m.buettner wokay, I figured that was trivial, but, added